# list Not taking whole input in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-2.7, split, user-input

I tried giving 300000 numbers in the list but the output shows just 1657

```
n,max_area=map(int,input().split())
s=[int(ele) for ele in input().split()]
print(len(s))

[link to test case][1]
  [1]: https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/163347/input01.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1590268059&Signature=6Q9CAYJaClPLuBncMcyj2YTgfyw%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain
```

Comment: you faced the issue on any online judge or in local? also try to include more details to help other reproduce the problem

Comment: I am facing this problem in local